# Bootstrap grid does not show properly

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I've been working on my webpage but somehow bootstrap would not show it properly. Below is my code:

```html
<div class="main-panel">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newGroupModal">
           <i class="ti-plus"></i>
          </button>
    <div class="row">
      <form method="post">
        <?php
            foreach($data as $row) {
        ?>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../../template/images/banner.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                    <?=$row['group_name']?>
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text"></p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="view_group.php?group_id=<?=$row['group_id']?>">View Group</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to be 3 column in a row but I ended up like this:

[Click here to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0IRa.png)

I'm not sure whats wrong with my code, if anybody could help me identify it would be great. Thank you so much

Comment: For  foreach($data as $row) --> Check the $data if you need 3 columns this $data should be 3, in your example I thik is 4

Comment: @Thomas_krk oh i thought it will automatically start in a new a row if i were to have > 3 $data? cause i wanted to display all the data i have in 3 columns per row?

Comment: This is what it does. In your example you have ONE row for the 3 first $data PLUS one row for the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="main-panel">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newGroupModal">
           <i class="ti-plus"></i>
          </button>
    <div class="row">
      
        <?php
            foreach($data as $row) {
        ?>
          <div class="col-4">
           <form method="post">
              <div class="card"> <div class="card-body">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../../template/images/banner.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                    <?=$row['group_name']?>
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text"></p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="view_group.php?group_id=<?=$row['group_id']?>">View Group</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explaination:

Change position of: `<form>` and `<form>`

Comment: "_For bootstrap 4, You use: col-4 instead of col-md-4_" Not quite true, Bootstrap 4 also supports `col-md-4`

Comment: sorry, after reading the manual: `col-12` `col-md-4` i am wrong